# Getting data off of a Graph into a table

Tags: vba, excel

[This is the yield calculator I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54uXm.png)

On the left of it is the input for the assay (crude oil) I'm getting in. It plots it on the graph, which has 6 horizontal lines at temperatures that are cutoffs for oils. Wherever the line crosses the horizontal Lines, I need to get that intersection point and put it in the table on the top right corner of the graph. Right now I'm just guesstimating the number rather than getting an exact one, and it's not automated. I've been trying to do something with VBA but am pretty lost.